# Oracle 11g OCA,OCP study material required

Tags: oracle11g

kindly let me know where to find this material.. need it urgently for preperation.

regards
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [OCA/OCP Oracle Database 11g All-in-One Exam Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Oracle-Database-All-Guide-CD-ROM/dp/0071629181/ref=pd_sim_b_8) by John Watson, Roopesh Ramklass and Bob Bryla. It is quite a thick book, but is easy to read. It contains everything you need to know for all three of the OCP exams. It also includes mock exam questions at the end of each chapter and some extra questions on the CD. The CD also includes the book in PDF format, which is useful for searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can find links to a great deal of study materials at the OracleCertificationPrep website.

http://www.oraclecertificationprep.com/apex/f?p=OCPSG:EXAM_DETAILS:0::NO::P2_EXAM:1Z0-052